# How to translate double-UTF-8-decoder code in Python to Lua

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, lua

I have this legacy code snippet, which (apparently) decodes double-encoded UTF-8 text back to normal UTF-8:

```
# Run with python3!
import codecs
import sys
s=codecs.open('doubleutf8.dat', 'r', 'utf-8').read()
sys.stdout.write(
                s
                .encode('raw_unicode_escape')
                .decode('utf-8')
        )
```

I need to translate it to Lua, and imitate all possible decoding side-effects (if any).

Limitations: I may use any of available Lua modules for UTF-8 handling, but preferably the stable one, with LuaRocks support. I will not use Lupa or other Lua-Python bridging solution, neither will I call `os.execute()` to invoke Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [lua-iconv](http://lua-iconv.luaforge.net/), the Lua binding to the [iconv library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/). With it you can convert between character encodings as much as you like.

It is also available in [LuaRocks](http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/).

**Edit**: using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177316/decoding-double-encoded-utf8-in-python/1178086#1178086) I have been able to correctly decode the data using the following Lua code:

```
require 'iconv'
-- convert from utf8 to latin1
local decoder = iconv.new('latin1', 'utf8')
local data = io.open('doubleutf8.dat'):read('*a')
-- decodedData is encoded in utf8
local decodedData = decoder:iconv(data)
-- if your terminal understands utf8, prints "нижний новгород"
-- if not, you can further convert it from utf8 to any encoding, like KOI8-R
print(decodedData)
```

Comment: Um, thanks, but the point of the question is that I'm a bit confused by the Python's UTF conversion stuff (what is the `raw_unicode_escape` for example?), and would like to see an actual piece of Lua code. Sorry for being lazy here.

Comment: A sample file would help, I don't know what data to expect, I will try to make an example with lua-iconv. Also, `raw_unicode_escape` means: 'Produce a string that is suitable as raw Unicode literal in Python source code'.

Comment: The bogus data (as encoded Lua string literal, join the strings): "\034\195\144\194\189\195\144\194\184\195\144\194\182\195"..
"\144\194\189\195\144\194\184\195\144\194\185\032\195\144"..
"\194\189\195\144\194\190\195\144\194\178\195\144\194\179"..
"\195\144\194\190\195\145\194\128\195\144\194\190\195\144"..
"\194\180\034"

Comment: I hope that I did not mess the encoding :)